# How to manage Nuget repositories config files on git, when developing on Windows and Mac (files always modified)?

Tags: windows, macos, git, nuget, repository

I'm beginning to have problems with the management of my repositories.config files of nuget packages.
On Windows it is used the backslash as directory separator. On Mac it is used the forward slash.
Whenever I work on any machine the file is overwritten, and subsequently it appears as modified on the git status.

Is it necessary to include on every commit these modified repositories files?
Is there a better way to manage this kind of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using NuGet package restore and not checking in the packages directory into source control. The repositories.config file will be regenerated by NuGet when the packages are restored.

I am guessing you are using MonoDevelop or Xamarin Studio on the Mac. The forward slash/back slash problem is a known bug that has not yet been fixed with NuGet inside these IDEs. The plan will be to always use back slashes on all operating systems in the same way that your MSBuild project files (.csproj) do.

Comment: Definitely this will solve my issues. And yes I'm using Mono on Mac and VS on Windows. Thanks

Comment: This is not the only issue with modified files. The file is converted to windows line endings and add the utf8 prefix at the beginning of the files.